# Apache Server and SVN 1.6.15

Tags: apache, svn

I have an older server running Apache and SVN (v1.6.15). I have some new laptops I need to configure SVN on. Will I have any issues connecting/committing/updating with different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, repository structure wasn't changed and 1.7 client backward compatible with 1.6 servers